# How could duplicate entry on unique key happen if only one master is active?

Tags: mysql, replication, multi-master

Say, I we have master-master replication with only one master active at a time.

We have users table:

```
create table users (
 id int auto_increment,
 email varchar(255),

 primary key id(id),
 unique key email(email)
);
```

and web application cluster which inserts new record for new users.

Now we got error which stopped replication:

```
Error 'Duplicate entry 'something@example.com-' for key 'email'' on query. Default database: 'xxx'. Query: 'INSERT INTO users  ...
```

Question is: is that true that this error in this setup is impossible, and probable reason of error is that we had two masters active at same time?

Answer (score 1):

Do not see the problem. When somebody enters the email address a second time then this happens. Nothing to do with replication. This is what the `unique key` is used for.

If this error would break the replication then I do not understand how replication could ever work. Every user could easily break the replication by, in this case, entering an email address 2 times.

I am not an MySQL expert but I think that the doc relates to errors other then maintaining data integrity. Perhaps somebody with more in-depth knowledge of clustering can help you on how to configure master-master clustering.

Comment: according to docs:

 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-features-slaveerrors.html

"If a statement produces the same error (identical error code) on both the master and the slave, the error is logged, but replication continues.

If a statement produces different errors on the master and the slave, the slave SQL thread terminates, and the slave writes a message to its error log and waits for the database administrator to decide what to do about the error"

So replication won't break on simple duplicate entry error.

Comment: Wrong. The replication you're using is "master-master" not "master-slave" if you want to skip "Duplicate entry" errors, you have to use **slave-skip-errors = 1062** in your **my.cnf** file. This is not recommended since you won't be able to look for keys problems.

Comment: But master-master replication with one master active *is* "master-slave" replication.

Comment: Don't use slave-skip-errors, that just lets the two servers get more and more out of sync!

Comment: @vsespb - true, but M-S is also setup in the other direction, yet no data is flowing that way.